# How to load a npm package to wasm_bindgen

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen, yew

I tried searching internet, couldn't find details how can I load a npm package to yew.

I am trying to load [@polkadot/extension-dapp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/extension-dapp) ( [code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension/blob/master/packages/extension-dapp/src/index.ts)  [docs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/extension))

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/node_modules/@polkadot/extension-dapp/index.js")]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub fn web3Enable(originName: String) -> JsValue;
}
```

It gives error:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@polkadot/util". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Comment: Done it with converting to individual js files: https://github.com/amiyatulu/polkadot-extension-on-yew

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing a dot at begin of the path? I highly doubt you have a node_modules fólder in the root of your filesystem.

Comment: @AmiyaBehera did you also figure out how to import any other npm packages from node_modules? i'm encountering the same original issue as you... but i'm trying to import @polkadot/api

Comment: @AmiyaBehera i found a solution that works for importing npm packages from node_modules https://stackoverflow.com/a/75717991/3208553

Comment: Ya successfully implement node package (@polkadot/api). Thank you.