# Using NPM packages with Rust and Webassembly

Tags: npm, rust, webassembly, npm-package

Is there a way to use npm packages inside Rust code along with webassembly? Right now using webpack, @wasm-tool/wasm-pack-plugin and wasm_bindgen crate that were already present in this template: https://github.com/rustwasm/rust-webpack-template/tree/master/template

TIA.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a way to use npm pakage inside your rust/wasm code.
Let's say you want to use date-fns package you installed with `npm i date-fns` and you want to use it inside your rust project.

Here's what I did. - Bundle your javascript and use it with wasm-bindgen
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjP4w.png)

As you can see in the picture, I have my node_modules/package.json, cargo.toml in the same folder for convenience sake.

1. `npm i esbuild` for esbuild. This is for bundling your javascript.
   this is my `esbuild.js`

```
esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['package.js'],
  bundle: true,
  outfile: 'src/package.js',
  format: 'esm',
  minify: true,
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

2. add build command in `package.json`
   `"esbuild":"node esbuild.js"`
3. create package.js for functions you want to export to rust project.

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

export function Dateformat(date, formatString) {
    return format(date, formatString);
}
```

4. run esbuild command `npm run esbuild` After running the command you will see the package.js in your src folder. That's the javascript code you can use in your rust project.
5. import javascript with wasm-bindgen

```
use js_sys::Date;
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;

#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/src/package.js")]
extern "C" {
    fn Dateformat(date: &Date, formatString: &str) -> String;
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn my_format(date: &Date, format_string: &str) -> String {
    Dateformat(date, format_string)
}
```

6. use the imported function in your rust/wasm project.

```
// this is the project set up with yew.
use js_sys::Date;
use yew::prelude::*;

use crate::pages::date_fns::my_format;

#[function_component(NpmCode)]
pub fn npm_code() -> Html {
    let date = use_state(|| Option::<String>::None);
    
    let onclick = {
        let date = date.clone();
        Callback::from(move |_| {
            let now = Date::new_0();
            let formatted_date = my_format(&now, "'Today is a' eeee");
            date.set(Some(formatted_date));
        })
    };

    html! {
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
            <p class="text-lg font-bold mb-2">{"This time is generated with date-fns npm package"}</p>
            <p class="text-gray-500 mb-4">{date.clone().as_ref().map(|d| d.as_str()).unwrap_or("null")}</p>
            <button class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded" {onclick}>
                {"Generate Date"}
            </button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

7. result [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xO18.png)

I also made a Proof of Concept where you directly download javascript in your browser using wasm-bindgen. In the link below.
https://github.com/jinseok9338/WASM-POC
I need to update the ReadMe. So you can understand better. It will be done in next few weeks.

Comment: Here's how I applied your approach. Please let me know if any objections to the open-source licensing https://github.com/maciejhirsz/kobold/pull/84

Comment: What about debugging? Is there any way to add source map?

Comment: Got it:   const esbuild = require('esbuild');

esbuild.build({
  entryPoints: ['package.js'],
  bundle: true,
  outfile: 'src/package.js',
  format: 'esm',
  sourcemap: 'inline',
  minify: true,
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));